# Group by and filter by on a particular field for all data in Django ORM

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, orm

I have following model:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have entered data like:

```
>>> leo_tolstoy = Author.objects.create(name=”Leo Tolstoy”)
>>> alexandre_dumas = Author.objects.create(name=”Alexandre Dumas”)
>>> Book.objects.create(title=”War and Peace”, author=leo_tolstoy)
>>> Book.objects.create(title=”Anna Karenina”, author=leo_tolstoy)
>>> Book.objects.create(title=”Resurrection”, author=leo_tolstoy)
>>> Book.objects.create(title=”The Three Musketeer”, author=alexandre_dumas)
>>> Book.objects.create(title=”The Count of Monte Cristo”, author=alexandre_dumas)
```

I want to print the author’s name and all the books he wrote. For all the authors we have in the database.
 Like this:
Leo Tolstoy: “War and Peace”, “Anna Karenina”, “Resurrection”
Alexandre Dumas: “The Three Musketeers”, “The Count of Monte Cristo”

I want to find the best solution for it but cannot find much. Any sort of help will be appreciated, I'm quite new to this.

Comment: `leo_tolstoy.book_set.all()`

Answer (score 2):

You can make a `ListView` of the `Author`s with:

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

class AuthorListView(ListView):
    model = Author
    queryset = Author.objects.prefetch_related('book_set')
    template_name = 'app_name/author_list.html'
```

and then in the template (`app_name/templates/app_name/author_list.html`) where you render the authors with:

```
<ul>
{% for author in object_list %}
    <li> {{ author.name }}
    <ul>
    {% for book in author.book_set.all %}
        <li>{{ book.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this...

But when you say "i want to print" im sure you mean much more than that! But, for the sake of an answer, here you are:

```
values = Author.objects.values('name', 'book_set__title')
leo = values.filter(name='Leo Tolstoy')
alex = values.filter(name='Alexandre Dumas')
print(f'{leo["name"]}: {", ".join(leo["book_set__title"]}')
print(f'{alex["name"]}: {", ".join(alex["book_set__title"]}')
```